# Django 1.9 ImportError: cannot import name <classname>

Tags: python, django

I just start learning django. I have a little problem and i can't solve it by myself.

I got class SingUpForm in forms.py but when I import this class in views.py i got error and I don't know why.

Error in the console :

```
\views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .forms import SignUpForm
ImportError: cannot import name 'SignUpForm'
```

views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import SignUpForm

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    title = "Welcome"
    #if request.user.is_authenticated():
    #    title = "Welcome %s" %(request.user)
    form = SignUpForm()
    context = {
        "title": title,
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

from .models import SignUp

import csv
with open('serialnumber.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    serial_number = list(reader)

class SingUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SignUp
        fields = ['full_name', 'email']


    def clean_full_name(self):
        full_name = self.cleaned_data.get('full_name')
        if not full_name in serial_number[0]:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Nieprawidłowy numer seryjny")
        return full_name
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class SignUp(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.

from .forms import SingUpForm
from .models import SignUp

class SignUpAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["__str__", "timestamp"]
    form = SingUpForm
    #class Meta:
    #    model = SignUp

admin.site.register(SignUp, SignUpAdmin)
```

Comment: If the files are in the same folder remove the `.`. If not you must learn how to create modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo, `sign` is not `sing`. Replace:

```
class SingUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
```

with:

```
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
```

<sup>Assuming you are not implementing a singing show form submission.</sup>

Comment: Omg! Thanks! I do it last night i was tired and i did not see that. Thank you very much. Now it's working. It was stupid mistake...

`Assuming you are not implementing a singing show form submission` :D